# Mouse Scroll stopped working in Kate 15.12.3 Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: mouse-scroll, kate

Mouse centre wheel Scroll stopped working in Kate v 15.12.3

Kubuntu 16.04

It also stopped in the Kate file open dialog it spawns.

Scrolling works an all other applications otherwise e.g. Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get mouse scrolling back in Kate (Kubuntu 16.04).

In system settings / hardware / input devices / mouse

Re booting rest it although after I had re-set, /system settings / hardware / input devices / mouse / reverse scroll direction, a couple of times.